# Add reviewers to environment using rest api github

Tags: rest, github

I'm trying to add reviewers to an environment on github using the repo rest [Api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-an-environment)

The problem is that I'm not sure what is the correct body for that, I am able to add timer using the next body code:

```
  -d '{ "wait_timer":42 }'
```

but when I try to add a reviewer using this:

```
-d '{ "wait_timer":42,
      "reviewers" : [
       { 
         "type": "User",
          "reviewer": 
          {
            "login": "user" 
          }
       }
     ]
    }'
```

It doesn't work, the documentation says that the users needs to be passed using array of objects

> reviewers array of objects or nullable    body     The people or teams that
> may review jobs that reference the environment. You can list up to six
> users or teams as reviewers. The reviewers must have at least read
> access to the repository. Only one of the required reviewers needs to
> approve the job for it to proceed.

Any Idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake, the correct payload for reviewers is

```
{ "wait_timer" : 1444,
   "reviewers" : [
  {
    "type" : "User",
     "id" : id_of_github_user
  }
]
```

}